# VueJS: How to pass data to a components from a v-for list

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my first question on Stack Overflow so I will try my best.

I'm building a an Vue application and I render a list of object coming from an API in a css grid, and when I click on a picture, I open a modale that show the full picture and some information about it, in clear, it's a copy of Instagram.

So the modale is a reusable components, and I use props for sending the data from the parent to the component child. And here is my problem, because I send the full list of data to the props and not only the information of the picture on which I clicked.

Is it possible to send only the information on the element I click, I know that it's possible with router-link but how to do it with props ?

here the code of the parent element:

```
<ul v-for="post in doc.posts" :key="post.id">
          <button v-on:click="toggleModale">
          <modal
            v-bind:revele="revele"
            v-bind:toggleModale="toggleModale"
            v-bind:media_url="post.media_url"
            v-bind:like_count="post.like_count"
          ></modal>
          <div class="post">
            <img class="postImage" :src="post.media_url" alt="" />
          </div>
           </button>
        </ul>
```

and the code of the child components modal :

```
    <template>
  <div v-if="revele" class="container">
    <div class="overlay" v-on:click="toggleModale"></div>
    <div class="modal">
      <button class="btnCls" v-on:click="toggleModale">X</button>
      <h2>Je suis un modal</h2>
      <div class="image"><img :src="media_url" alt=""></div>
      <div class="text">{{like_count}}</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "modal",
  props: ['revele', 'toggleModale', 'media_url', 'media_type', 'like_count', 'comments_count', 'timestamp', 'permalink', 'id'],
  created() {
    console.log("test modal props id",this.id)  //undefined;
  },
};
</script>
```

thanks in advance for your help

UPDATE the code sandbox :

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-andras-tmyqc?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: So your child component holds the data as they passed via `v-for`, instead of after click on the image, send the information to child component? Actually, I think this is just how a component works (it requires information before mounting).

Comment: Otherwise, you don't set those `props` to *send* info, but using an event, like `beforeMount()` for your child component, and so, fetch the information from your server or do anything else to *get* the information from your child component side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your architecture is a little strange to be honest but i made you a working Sandbox

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-wood-gd4kn?file=/src/App.vue)

please check the code first and if you need help understanding i will explain you what i did.

Comment: I have an answer in the console that say "Uncaught TypeError: _ctx.doSomething is not a function"
Apparently, the parent can't access the child function

Comment: otherwise are you able to make a CodeSandbox?

Comment: Yes here it is :

Comment: @FlorentAyot i updated my answer please take a look

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks a lot for the help @Deniz. not surprise about the architecture has it is my first app and I'm self-taught, so yeah, I probably have a lot of mistakes

Comment: @FlorentAyot and doing mistakes is something very good and important trust me :) nice job btw. Please mark my "Answer" as solved.